# Shiny/Leaflet - Highlighting specific area on map

Tags: shiny, leaflet, rstudio

I'm creating a leaflet map with defined areas, I already use events that return information about the area when the mouse go over it but now I want to make the map dynamic and highlight the polygon where my pointer is. I think I should use leafletproxy() inside an observeEvent, but for now I can't make it work.

Comment: yeah, code will ofcourse help

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this](https://jcheng.shinyapps.io/choropleth3/)? It will get a little complicated, but basically you will want to add a function that takes as an argument whether it should be bolded. In the example, it would be `drawStates()`.

The simplified idea is then to:

1. Render all polygons (including Polygons A and B).
2. (Move mouse pointer over Polygon A.)
3. Recreate Polygon A where mouse is, but this time make it bold.
4. (Move mouse pointer to Polygon B.)
5. Recreate Polygon A and make it not bold.
6. Recreate Polygon B and make it bold.

Without your code I can't say much else.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about recreating the map each time the mouse go over a new polygon, but first i don't understand very much how the addPolygons option works in leaflet and how the polygons are defined (i use a map from the packages "maps" already design). Here is the part of my code that build the map :

```
output$prodmap <- renderLeaflet({ 

  pal <- colorQuantile("Reds",domain = mapdata(),na.color = "grey", probs = 0.2)
  palleg <- colorNumeric("Reds",domain=mapdata(),na.color = "grey")

  map=leaflet(data = mapStates(),width =500 , height =800 ) %>% addTiles() %>% 
      addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(mapdata()) , color="black",weight=1 , fillOpacity = 0.7) %>%
      addLegend("topleft", pal = palleg, values = mapdata(),
                title = "Production 2014 :",
                labFormat = labelFormat(suffix= " q/ha"),
                opacity = 1 )
  return(map)
})

reg=reactive({
   return(
     reg=map.where(database = "france", input$prodmap_shape_mouseover[4],input$prodmap_shape_mouseover[3]))})
```

So "mapdata()" return a vector with data sort by area, for now I used map.where() and mouseover event to create a reactive which return the name of the area. I think I should write a reactive that create a new map for each position of the pointer but how could I add a new polygon with the name or coordinates of the area ?

Thanks